# Settings are not saved as expected in Word Online

Tags: office365api

I have the problem with **Office.context.document.settings** object.

This occurs only in Word Online and works fine for locally installed MS Word 2016 desktop version.

So, I created Word Add-In with two buttons. In the **Manifest.xml** file first button described as

**`<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">`**
second described as

**`<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">`**

My actions:

press first button, opens a task pane. Then the code executes like this:

```
Office.context.document.settings.set("name", "value");
Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync(function(asyncResult) {
        console.log("persistOfficeSettings");
        console.log(asyncResult);
    });
```

In the console I see that everything is good, status: "succeeded" for asyncResult object.

Then I press second button, the code executes like this:

```
var name = Office.context.document.settings.get("name");
```

As result, name is **null**. I expect **name="value"** because it was saved earlier, but is is **null**.

Why it does not work in Word Online? How to fix this?

(it works successfully in locally installed Word 2016 desktop version)